# Is access to DAOS objects transparent to the Java API?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

An article about DAOS on IBM's developerWorks site ([IBM Lotus Domino going green: The new Lotus Domino attachment and object service](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-green/)) mentions that

> Attachment consolidation is completely transparent to users.

and

> Access to DAOS objects is transparent to the Lotus Domino server and applications:
>
> - Lotus Notes large objects are encrypted and controlled by Lotus Notes ACLs.
> - DAOS is transparent to C API calls, agents, and LotusScript®.

Is DAOS transparent to Java API calls too? I guess it is but I'd appreciate some confirmation or information (sample codes etc.) if it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. As the Java calls do not interact with the NSF directly, the Java code never notices any changes to the database structure.